# Remove rows not .isin('X')

Tags: python, filtering, pandas

Sorry just getting into Pandas, this seems like it should be a very straight forward question. How can I use the `isin('X')` to remove rows that **are in** the list `X`? In R I would write `!which(a %in% b)`.

Answer (score 162):

You have many options. Collating some of the answers above and the [accepted answer from this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19960077/how-to-implement-in-and-not-in-for-pandas-dataframe) you can do:
1. `df[-df["column"].isin(["value"])]`
2. `df[~df["column"].isin(["value"])]`
3. `df[df["column"].isin(["value"]) == False]`
4. `df[np.logical_not(df["column"].isin(["value"]))]`

Note: for option 4 for you'll need to `import numpy as np`

**Update:** You can also use the `.query` method for this too. This allows for [method chaining](https://tomaugspurger.github.io/method-chaining):
5.  `df.query("column not in @values")`.
where `values` is a list of the values that you don't want to include.

Comment: What is the difference between `~` and `-`? Is this pandas-specific?

Comment: @stragu I don't think this is Pandas-specific. The `~` [is a bitwise operation](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46054354/4543854) which in this case leads to the same result as using `-`. But Unfortunately, I don't know enough about Bitwise operators to give an in-depth answer to your question

Comment: Time profiling/scaling..?

Answer (score 75):

You can use [`numpy.logical_not`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.logical_not.html#numpy.logical_not) to invert the boolean array returned by `isin`:

```
In [63]: s = pd.Series(np.arange(10.0))

In [64]: x = range(4, 8)

In [65]: mask = np.logical_not(s.isin(x))

In [66]: s[mask]
Out[66]: 
0    0
1    1
2    2
3    3
8    8
9    9
```

As given in the comment by Wes McKinney you can also use

```
s[~s.isin(x)]
```

Answer (score 30):

All you have to do is create a subset of your dataframe where the isin method evaluates to False:

```
df = df[df['Column Name'].isin(['Value']) == False]
```

Answer (score 5):

You can use the [`DataFrame.select`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html#the-select-method) method:

```
In [1]: df = pd.DataFrame([[1,2],[3,4]], index=['A','B'])

In [2]: df
Out[2]: 
   0  1
A  1  2
B  3  4

In [3]: L = ['A']

In [4]: df.select(lambda x: x in L)
Out[4]: 
   0  1
A  1  2
```

Comment: Thanks Hayden, sorry I had a typo in my question, I wanted to select those which are not in A, so something that I could know A, and it would give me back B instead.