# How to check if a value is in the list in selection from pandas data frame?

Tags: python, select, numpy, pandas, dataframe

Looks ugly:

```
df_cut = df_new[
             (
             (df_new['l_ext']==31) |
             (df_new['l_ext']==22) |
             (df_new['l_ext']==30) |
             (df_new['l_ext']==25) |
             (df_new['l_ext']==64)
             )
            ]
```

Does not work:

```
df_cut = df_new[(df_new['l_ext'] in [31, 22, 30, 25, 64])]
```

Is there an elegant and working solution of the above "problem"?

Answer (score 251, accepted):

Use [isin](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/dev/generated/pandas.Series.isin.html#pandas.Series.isin)

```
df_new[df_new['l_ext'].isin([31, 22, 30, 25, 64])]
```

Comment: This is one of those less-intuitive `pandas` syntax features... You don't know unless you know.

Comment: What's the negative of isin? I'm looking for a way to filter out the list elements.

Comment: numpy.logical_not(foo.isin(x)) and another method suggested by Pandas author: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14057007/remove-rows-not-isinx

Comment: Negation using ~ should be enough for doing not isin. df_new[~df_new['l_ext'].isin([31, 22, 30, 25, 64])]

Comment: Be cautious, if the type of the column is ambiguous for example "object" which could be either numeric or string "isin" will automatically infer data type.

Comment: What if it is a list of sets that I need to check if a value in a column is a subset of?  For example, the defined values list is given by `[{a, b}, {c, d}, {e, f}]`, where `a, b, c...`  are some values (say `strings`).  Thank you

Answer (score 16):

You can use [`pd.DataFrame.query`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.query.html):

```
select_values = [31, 22, 30, 25, 64]
df_cut = df_new.query('l_ext in @select_values')
```

In the background, this uses the top-level [`pd.eval`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.eval.html) function.

Comment: Another alternative without having to create an extra variable:
`df_new.query('l_ext.isin([31, 22, 30, 25, 64]).values')`