# In Python, how do I assign a value to ColB based off of my ColA value?

Tags: python, dataframe, conditional-statements

I currently have a list and 1 table with 2 col names

list = [a,b,c]

TableA has colA and colB.

I want to set the value in colB depending on my value in colA.

if list is in col A, set col B to 1. Else, set col B to 0.

I've tried this loop but it's inefficient due to my large dataset.

```
for i in TableA['colA']:
    if '' in i :
        TableA['colB'] = '0'
    elif 'list value 1' in i:
        TableA['colB'] = '0'
    elif 'list value 2' in i:
        TableA['colB'] = '0'
    elif 'list value 3' in i:
        TableA['colB'] = '0'
    else:
       TableA['colB'] = '1'
```

Please help with something more efficient.

Comment: Looping over a dataframe is almost never the best option. In this case, I believe the built-in method you're looking for is [isin()](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.isin.html)

Comment: Could you please assit with syntax? I'm very new to Python. Something like, if df[[colA]] in List then colB = 1, else colB=0?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to check if a value is in the list in selection from pandas data frame?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18250298/how-to-check-if-a-value-is-in-the-list-in-selection-from-pandas-data-frame)

Comment: Basically, `df['colb']=df['cola'].isin(my_list).astype(int)` (don't name variables things like `list`, as that will shadow the built-in and frustrate you later, andthe `astype` will force the bool True, False to 1 and 0)

Comment: Your comment above is not quite what I am trying to do. I have attempted this which is what I want …. (if df['cola'].isin(List):  
        df['colb'] = '1' 
else:
        df['cola'] = '2')  …. but I get this error..... (ValueError: The truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all().)

Answer (score 0):

I would probably write if '' == i rather than in i. i is the element of the list, not the entire list, so it would not be "in" the element, it would be equal to the element.

Answer (score 0):

Let's break down what you intend to do:
1) Filter by criteria
2) Set values accordingly

For 1), you can create a boolean Series to represent the criteria like @G. Anderson suggested in the comments, like so:

```
TableA['colA'].isin(value_list)
```

Side note: for the *not* `isin`, add `~` like so: `~TableA['colA'].isin(value_list)`

Proceed to 2), default `colB` to zero:

```
TableA['colB'] = 0
```

Then set values to 1 according to criteria:

```
TableA.loc[TableA['colA'].isin(value_list), 'colB'] = 1
```

Last note: please don't use variable names that collide with [built-in functions](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html) like `list`.