# Extracting information from a data frame if certain columns of the row are in a pre-defined list

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a list like this:

```
list1 = ['4361', '1856', '57586', '79017', '972', '974', '1829', '10787', '85477', '57019', '7431', '53616', '26228', '29085', '5217', '5527']
```

And then I have two columns of a data frame like this:

```
print(df['col A'][0:10])
0      6416
1     84665
2        90
3      2624
4      6118
5       375
6       377
7       377
9       351
10      333


print(df['col B'][0:10])
0      2318
1        88
2      2339
3      5371
4      6774
5     23163
6     23647
7     27236
9     10513
10     1600
```

I want to say 'return only the rows in the data frame, if an item in the list is either in col A or col B of the data frame'.

I could imagine how to do this iteratively, something like this:

```
for each_item in list1:
    for i,row in df.iterrows():
         if each_item in row['col A']:
               print(row)
         if each_item in row['col B']:
               print (row)
```

I'm just wondering if there's a neater way to do it where I don't have to continually loop through the dataframe, as both the list and the dataframe are quite big.

I saw this code snippet online, where this would return the rows where `df['col A']` equals a value OR `df['col B']` equals a value:

```
print(df[(df["col A"]==1) | (df_train["col A"]==2)]
```

I'm just unsure how to convert this to pulling out the data if it's in a list. Can someone show me how to perhaps incorporate this kind of idea into my code, or do people think my original code snippet (using .iterrows()) is the best way?

Comment: Does this answer your question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18250298/how-to-check-if-a-value-is-in-the-list-in-selection-from-pandas-data-frame?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`isin`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.isin.html):

```
print(df[(df['col A'].isin(list1)) | (df['col B'].isin(list1))])
```