# Apply condition on pandas columns to create a boolen indexing array

Tags: python, pandas

I want to drop specific rows from a pandas dataframe. Usually you can do that using something like

```
df[df['some_column'] != 1234]
```

What `df['some_column'] != 1234` does is creating an indexing array that is indexing the new df, thus letting only rows with value `True` to be present.

But in some cases, like mine, I don't see how I can express the condition in such a way, and iterating over pandas rows is way too slow to be considered a viable option.

To be more specific, I want to drop all rows where the value of a column is also a key in a dictionary, in a similar manner with the example above.

In a perfect world I would consider something like

```
df[df['some_column'] not in my_dict.keys()]
```

Which is obviously not working. Any suggestions?

Comment: In your pseudo code example, did you mean `... not in my_dict]`?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to implement 'in' and 'not in' for Pandas dataframe](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19960077/how-to-implement-in-and-not-in-for-pandas-dataframe)

Comment: This is called boolean indexing by the way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you're looking for is `isin()`

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame([[1, 2], [1, 3], [4, 6],[5,7],[8,9]], columns=['A', 'B'])
In[9]: df
Out[9]: df
   A  B
0  1  2
1  1  3
2  4  6
3  5  7
4  8  9
mydict = {1:'A',8:'B'}
df[df['A'].isin(mydict.keys())]
Out[11]: 
   A  B
0  1  2
1  1  3
4  8  9
```

Comment: `.isin(mydict)` works just fine on its own, you don't need to specify keys.

Answer (score 1):

You could use [`query`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html#special-use-of-the-operator-with-list-objects) for this purpose:

```
df.query('some_column != list(my_dict.keys()')
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the function [`isin()`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.isin.html) to select rows whose column value is in an iterable.

#### Using lists:

```
my_list = ['my', 'own', 'data']
df.loc[df['column'].isin (my_list)]
```

#### Using dicts:

```
my_dict = {'key1':'Some value'}
df.loc[df['column'].isin (my_dict.keys())]
```