# Create Pandas DataFrames from Unique Values in one Column

Tags: python, pandas

I have a Pandas dataframe with 1000s of rows. and it has the `Names` column includes the customer names and their records. I want to create individual dataframes for each customer based on their unique names. I got the unique names into a list

`customerNames = DataFrame['customer name'].unique().tolist()` this gives the following array

```
['Name1', 'Name2', 'Name3, 'Name4']
```

I tried a loop by catching the unique names in the above list and creating dataframes for each name and assign the dataframes to the customer name. So for example when I write `Name3`, it should give the `Name3`'s data as a separate dataframe

```
for x in customerNames:
    x = DataFrame.loc[DataFrame['customer name'] == x]
x
```

Above lines returned the dataframe for only `Name4` as dataframe result, but skipped the rest.

How can I solve this problem?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Your current iteration overwrites `x` twice every time it runs: the `for` loop assigns a customer name to `x`, and then you assign a dataframe to it.

To be able to call each dataframe later by name, try storing them in a dictionary:

```
df_dict = {name: df.loc[df['customer name'] == name] for name in customerNames}

df_dict['Name3']
```

Answer (score 9):

To create a dataframe for all the unique values in a column, create a `dict` of dataframes, as follows.

- Creates a `dict`, where each key is a unique value from the column of choice and the value is a dataframe.
- Access each dataframe as you would a standard dict (e.g. `df_names['Name1']`)
- [`.groupby()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html) creates a [generator](https://realpython.com/introduction-to-python-generators/), which can be unpacked.

  - `k` is the unique values in the column and `v` is the data associated with each `k`.

### With a `for-loop` and `.groupby`:

```py
df_names = dict()
for k, v in df.groupby('customer name'):
    df_names[k] = v
```

### With a [Python Dictionary Comprehension](https://www.datacamp.com/community/tutorials/python-dictionary-comprehension)

- [PEP 274 -- Dict Comprehensions](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0274/)

#### Using `.groupby`

```py
df_names = {k: v for (k, v) in df.groupby('customer name')}
```

- This comes from a conversation with [rafaelc](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2535611/rafaelc), who pointed out that using `.groupby` is faster than `.unique`.

  - With 6 unique values in the column, `.groupby` is faster, at 104 ms compared to 392 ms
  - With 26 unique values in the column, `.groupby` is faster, at 147 ms compared to 1.53 s.
- Using an a `for-loop` is slightly faster than a comprehension, particularly for more unique column values or lots of rows (e.g. 10M).

#### Using `.unique`:

- Use [Boolean indexing](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html#boolean-indexing) to match the unique values in the column of choice.

```py
df_names = {name: df[df['customer name'] == name] for name in df['customer name'].unique()}
```

### Testing

- The following data was used for testing

```py
import pandas as pd
import string
import random

random.seed(365)

# 6 unique values
data = {'class': [random.choice(['1-5', '6-25', '26-100', '100-500', '500-1000', '>1000']) for _ in range(1000000)],
        'treatment': [random.choice(['Yes', 'No']) for _ in range(1000000)]}

# 26 unique values
data = {'class': [random.choice( list(string.ascii_lowercase)) for _ in range(1000000)],
        'treatment': [random.choice(['Yes', 'No']) for _ in range(1000000)]}

df = pd.DataFrame(data)
```

Answer (score 0):

maybe i get you wrong but

when

```
for x in customerNames:
    x = DataFrame.loc[DataFrame['customer name'] == x]
x
```

gives you the right output for the last list entry its because your output is out of the indent of the loop

```
import pandas as pd

customer_df = pd.DataFrame.from_items([('A', ['Jean', 'France']), ('B', ['James', 'USA'])],
                        orient='index', columns=['customer', 'country'])

customer_list = ['James', 'Jean']

for x in customer_list:
    x = customer_df.loc[customer_df['customer'] == x]
    print(x)
    print('now I could append the data to something new')
```

you get the output:

```
  customer country
B    James     USA
now I could append the data to something new
  customer country
A     Jean  France
now I could append the data to something new
```

Or if you dont like loops you could go with

```
import pandas as pd

customer_df = pd.DataFrame.from_items([('A', ['Jean', 'France']), ('B', ['James', 'USA']),('C', ['Hans', 'Germany'])],
                        orient='index', columns=['customer', 'country'])

customer_list = ['James', 'Jean']


print(customer_df[customer_df['customer'].isin(customer_list)])
```

Output:

```
  customer country
A     Jean  France
B    James     USA
```

df.isin is better explained under:[How to implement 'in' and 'not in' for Pandas dataframe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19960077/how-to-implement-in-and-not-in-for-pandas-dataframe)