# Create One Dataframe per unique Values in Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, loops

**Hello World**,

I would to create One Dataframe per unique value from one column.

Below is my initial Dataframe.

```
Date     Name     Value
01/19     Jean        15
01/19     Jean        15
01/17     Bean        15
01/16     Bean        15
01/19     Jean        15
```

I have found some answers concerning the creation of dataframes based on unique values, such as : [Create Pandas DataFrames from Unique Values in one Column](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44722436/create-pandas-dataframes-from-unique-values-in-one-column).

With the following code, I am having everything within a list.

```
dfa = [x for _, x in df.groupby('name')]
dfa[0]

output 
Date     Name     Value
01/19     Jean        15
01/19     Jean        15
01/19     Jean        15
Date     Name     Value
01/17     Bean        15
01/16     Bean        15
```

However, I would like to assign the name of dataframe automatically and not doing:

```
df_Jean= df[0]
df_Bean= df[1]
```

Below are the expected output

```
df_Jean
Date     Name     Value
01/19     Jean        15
01/19     Jean        15
01/19     Jean        15
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is possible, but not [recommended](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30638956) in python:

```
for i, g in df.groupby('name'):
    globals()['df_' + str(i)] =  g
```

Or:

```
for i, g in df.groupby('name'):
    globals()[f'df_{i}'] =  g
```

Better is use `dict`:

```
d = dict(tuple(df.groupby("Name")))

print (d['Jean'])
print (d['Bean'])
```

Comment: thanks @jezrael, this do the job :) However, do you know how to name each dataframe as df1, df2, .. instead of names (might be more efficient if I want to loop after)

Answer (score 2):

You should use a dict:

```
d = {k:v for k, v in df.groupby("Name")}
```

Then you can simply pass the names as key:

```
print (d["Jean"])

    Date  Name  Value
0  01/19  Jean     15
1  01/19  Jean     15
4  01/19  Jean     15
```