# How to take column of dataframe in pandas

Tags: python, pandas

now I have this dataframe:

```
      A    B    C
0     m   1    b
1     n   4    a
2     p   3    c
3     o   4    d
4     k   6    e
```

so,How I can get **n,p,k** in column。as follow:

```
      A    B    C
0     n   4    a
1     p   3    c
2     k   6    e
```

thanks

Comment: https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html

Comment: What's the logic here? Are n, p and k arbitrary values that you'd like to pass in a list?

Comment: It seems you need `df[df.A.isin(['n','p','k'])]`

Comment: Check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19960077/how-to-implement-in-and-not-in-for-pandas-dataframe) - dupe

Comment: thanks for you help @jezrael

Answer (score 2):

Use .loc

```
df = df.loc[df.A.isin(['n','p','k']),:]
```