# Pandas: Check value exist in a Column, which is stored as list

Tags: python, pandas

I have the below data frame. The status column stores the value as a list.

df

```
   STATUS     
1 [REQUESTED, RECEIVED]
2 [XYZ]
3 [RECEIVED]
```

When I try the below logic:

```
df['STATUS'].str.upper().isin(['RECEIVED'])
```

It gives me

```
1 False
2 False
3 False
```

But I am expecting

```
1 True
2 False
3 True
```

as we have the value `RECEIVED` at rows 1 and 3

Comment: It looks like you have a typo in 3. - it should be RECEIVED and not RECIEVED.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For a simple check like this, you can join the list of strings and use `contains`.

EDIT:
To account for the difference between `RECEIVED` and `RECEIVED CASH`, you can join the lists with a unique character (such as `'='`) AND surround the resulting string with the same character, and then check for `=RECEIVED=`.

```
('=' + df['STATUS'].str.join('=') + '=').str.contains('=RECEIVED=')
```

Comment: I am reconsidering the usage of contains as it fails to distinguish between ~RECEIVED~ and ~RECEIVED CASH~

Answer (score 1):

It's possible you mean something like

```
>>> df.STATUS.astype(str).str.upper().str.contains('RECEIVED')
1 True
2 False
3 False
```

(Your example has a typo, incidentally - 1. has RECEIVED and 3. has RECIEVED.)

as `isin` is the opposite of what is meant by your example.

Comment: it gives me the error `Series object has no attribute contains`

Comment: Are you sure you placed `.str` after `upper()`?

Comment: but in this question i saw something similar about isin https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19960077/how-to-implement-in-and-not-in-for-pandas-dataframe

Comment: @TomJMuthirenthi Yes, that is the exact opposite than this question, no? In that question, each of the series elements is a single string, and the point is to check if this string is in a list. Here each series element is a list, and the point is to check if the list *contains* a string. LMK if I'm missing something.

Comment: So, how can we write the equivalent for a df `select * from df where col in (5,6)` ? Please help.

Comment: @TomJMuthirenthi That would indeed be using `isin`, but it is the opposite case of your question here, AFAIU. In `SELECT * .. WHERE col IN (5, 6)`, `col` is implicitly a column of scalars.

Comment: So you mean to say, since STATUS column holds list, it is causing the confusion?

Comment: @TomJMuthirenthi Yes. In this case `STATUS` column holds lists, and you're checking if each one *contains* something, not if it's *contained in* something, AFAIU.

Comment: In that case should it print true for case 3, right?

Answer (score 1):

It's hard to operate directly with list values. You can concatenate the strings into one, using some separator character, and then check the condition:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'STATUS': [['REQUESTED', 'RECEIVED'], ['XYZ'], ['RECEIVED']]},
                  index=[1, 2, 3])
print(df['STATUS'].str.join('|').str.contains('RECEIVED'))
```

Output:

```
1     True
2    False
3     True
Name: STATUS, dtype: bool
```

A more efficient option would be to replace the strings with numerical flags. This can be done really nicely since Python 3.6 using [`enum.Flag`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/enum.html#flag).

```
import enum
import pandas as pd

class Status(enum.Flag):
    REQUESTED = enum.auto()
    RECEIVED = enum.auto()
    XYZ = enum.auto()

df = pd.DataFrame({'STATUS': [Status.REQUESTED | Status.RECEIVED, Status.XYZ, Status.RECEIVED]}, index=[1, 2, 3])
print(df['STATUS'] & Status.RECEIVED)
```

Or, if you already have a data frame with strings:

```
import enum
import pandas as pd
from functools import reduce

class Status(enum.Flag):
    REQUESTED = enum.auto()
    RECEIVED = enum.auto()
    XYZ = enum.auto()

df = pd.DataFrame({'STATUS': [['REQUESTED', 'RECEIVED'], ['XYZ'], ['RECEIVED']]}, index=[1, 2, 3])
df['STATUS_ENUM'] = df['STATUS'].apply(lambda v: reduce(lambda a, b: a | Status[b], v, Status(0)))
print(df['STATUS_ENUM'] & Status.RECEIVED)
```

Comment: I am reconsidering the usage of `contains` as it fails to distinguish between `RECEIVED` and `RECEIVED CASH`

Comment: @TomJMuthirenthi Yes, this approach has that kind of limitations... You could do something like `contains('RECEIVED|')`, but you would need to append a `|` to each row after `join`...

Answer (score 1):

Data from jde

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'STATUS': [['REQUESTED', 'RECEIVED'], ['XYZ'], ['RECEIVED']]},
                  index=[1, 2, 3])
df.STATUS.apply(lambda x : 'RECEIVED' in x)
Out[11]: 
1     True
2    False
3     True
Name: STATUS, dtype: bool
```