# Filtering a dataset on values not in another dataset

Tags: python, pandas, function, filter, formatting

I am looking to filter a dataset  based off of whether a certain ID **does not** appear in a different dataframe.

While I'm not super attached to the way in which I've decided to do this if there's a better way that I'm not familiar with, I want to apply a Boolean function to my dataset, put the results in a new column, and then filter the entire dataset off of that True/False result.

My main dataframe is `df`, and my other dataframe with the `ID`'s in it is called `ID`:

```
def groups():
    if df['owner_id'] not in ID['owner_id']:
        return True
    return False
```

This ends up being accepted (no syntax problems), so I then go to apply it to my dataframe, which fails:

```
df['ID Groups?'] = df.apply (lambda row: groups() ,axis=1)
```

Result:

```
TypeError: ("'Series' objects are mutable, thus they cannot be hashed", 'occurred at index 0')
```

It seems that somewhere my data that I'm trying to use (the ID's are both letters and numbers, so strings) is incorrectly formatted.

I have two questions:

1. Is my proposed method the best way of going about this?
2. How can I fix the error that I'm seeing?

My apologies if it's something super obvious, I have very limited exposure to Python and coding as a whole, but I wasn't able to find anywhere where this type of question had already been addressed.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to implement 'in' and 'not in' for Pandas dataframe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19960077/how-to-implement-in-and-not-in-for-pandas-dataframe)

Comment: error is because you are trying to insert `data frame` into a `series` object

Comment: `~df['owner_id'].isin(ID['owner_id'].unique())` will give you your boolean Series

Answer (score 1):

Expression to keep only these rows in `df` that match `owner_id` in `ID`:

```
df = df[df['owner_id'].isin(ID['owner_id'])]
```

Lambda expression is going to be way slower that this.

`isin` is the Pandas way. `not in` is the Python collections way.

The reason you are getting this error is `df['owner_id'] not in ID['owner_id']` hashes left hand side to figure out if it is present in the right hand side. `df['owner_id']` is of type `Series` and is not hashable, as reported. Luckily, it is not needed.