# Populate a column based on the value of other column

Tags: python, pandas

Lets say I have a list

```
vowels= ['a','e','i','o','u']
```

I have a pandas dataframe

```
id       alphabet
 1         b
 2         a
 3         c
 4         i
```

I need output like

```
id       alphabet  label
 1         b         
 2         a       vowel
 3         c
 4         i       vowel
```

I tried

```
df.loc[df.alphabet in vowels, 'label'] = "vowel"
```

This gives me a error. how do i do this?

Comment: df.loc[df['alphabet'].isin(vowels), 'activity'] = "vowel". Make sure alphabet column has strings for this to work. Secondly,

Comment: Your code is right, see this duplicate on how to use `in` logic in dfs (use `isin` and not `in`): https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19960077/how-to-implement-in-and-not-in-for-pandas-dataframe

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think need function [`Series.isin`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.isin.html) for condition.

If need missing values with `vowel` use:

```
df.loc[df.alphabet.isin(vowels), 'activity'] = "vowel"
print (df)
   id alphabet activity
0   1        b      NaN
1   2        a    vowel
2   3        c      NaN
3   4        i    vowel
```

Or if need empty values and `vowel` use [`numpy.where`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.where.html):

```
df['activity'] = np.where(df.alphabet.isin(vowels), 'vowel', '')
print (df)
   id alphabet activity
0   1        b         
1   2        a    vowel
2   3        c         
3   4        i    vowel
```

Comment: I guess it should be stated that the first block of code and the second block do different things

Comment: @RafaelC - Yes, so added both outputs.