# How to compare Pandas dataframe values with a list, and put the result in a new column

Tags: python, pandas

I have the following dataset for Manhattan neighborhoods with the most common venues in each neighborhood:

[df](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xb4xt.png)

I made a list of venues:

`fit_venues = ['Coffee Shop', 'Café', 'Park', 'Hotel', 'Sandwich Place', 'Pizza Place', 'Gym / Fitness Center', 'Exhibit', 'Gym', 'Supermarket', 'Nightclub', 'Concert Hall', 'Jazz Club']`

and I want to add a column to the dataframe (let's call it "Fit Neighborhood" for example), and compare the most common venues of each neighborhood (5 columns) with the list "fit_venues". Then we assign the result to the column "Fit Neighborhood" (Yes/No or True/False). For example, the first two rows should return Yes/True and the third row should return No/False.

Any help?

Comment: Welcome! Can you please add a minimal sample of your input data as text, and provide the corresponding output you want? And also provide any attempts you have already made to produce the output.

Comment: Please edit your question to add the output of `print(yourdataframe.head())` so we can see what kind of data you are working with.

Comment: There's a similar question with an extended explanation [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19960077/how-to-filter-pandas-dataframe-using-in-and-not-in-like-in-sql)

Answer (score 1):

See if this works:

```
 fit_venues = ['Coffee Shop', 'Café', 'Park', 'Hotel', 'Sandwich Place', 'Pizza Place', 'Gym / Fitness Center', 'Exhibit', 'Gym', 'Supermarket', 'Nightclub', 'Concert Hall', 'Jazz Club']

df["binary_check"] = df[df["5th Most Common Venue"].isin(fit_venues)]
```

Comment: It gives me error: ValueError: Wrong number of items passed 7, placement implies 1

However, I need to compare with all common venues columns from 1st to 5th.

Comment: Not sure why this worked for my case but == did not work. This worked for me **final_table[final_table["Items"].isin([['I2','I3']])]** but this did not work **final_table[final_table.Items == "['I1', 'I2']"].Items**  but

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried using [`DataFrame.isin()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.isin.html)?

You didn't give me the names of your most common venue columns, so I'll assume they are the only columns in the DataFrame (`df`):

```
fit_venues = ['Coffee Shop', 'Café', 'Park', 'Hotel', 'Sandwich Place', 'Pizza Place', 'Gym / Fitness Center', 'Exhibit', 'Gym', 'Supermarket', 'Nightclub', 'Concert Hall', 'Jazz Club']

df['Fit Neighborhood'] = df.isin(fit_venues).any()
```

Comment: I did. It assigned NaN for all!

Comment: Did you try it without any() also?

Comment: Yes, it assigned False to all records