# Filtering one CSV based on a Column in another CSV

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I've got 2 CSV files.

The first CSV is a small dataset that looks like:

CSV ONE.csv`

```
COLUMN A    COLUMN B    COLUMN C    COLUMN D    COLUMN E
    1          XYZ          A            B           D
    2          YZX.12       E            F           G
    3          ZYX.567      H            I           J
```

Second CSV is a much larger dataset that looks like:

CSV TWO.csv

```
COLUMN A   COLUMN B   COLUMN C   COLUMN D   COLUMN E   COLUMN F   COLUMN G
   1        ZYX.567       A          B          D         AAA        ABB
   2        SAMPLE A      E          F          G         BBB        ACA  
   3        SAMPLE B      H          I          J         CCC        BBC 
   4        XYZ           A          B          D         ABA        BBA
   5        SAMPLE C      E          F          G         ABC        BAB
   6        YZX.12        H          I          J         CCA        CAC
```

I want my output to be CSV TWO but only with COLUMN B from CSV ONE:

```
COLUMN A   COLUMN B   COLUMN C   COLUMN D   COLUMN E   COLUMN F   COLUMN G
   1        ZYX.567       A          B          D         AAA        ABB
   4        XYZ           A          B          D         ABA        BBA
   6        YZX.12        H          I          J         CCA        CAC
```

I am using Pandas data frames... Any help you can provide will be much appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to implement 'in' and 'not in' for Pandas dataframe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19960077/how-to-implement-in-and-not-in-for-pandas-dataframe)

Comment: Imagine that columns A, C, D, E are different in CSV TWO then in CSV ONE. So only Column B can be used to match.

Comment: Also relevant, the inner join on `'COLUMN B'`: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53645882/pandas-merging-101

Comment: Is there a unique key?

Answer (score 1):

This is a `merge` problem with selecting only the relevant columns from your right dataframe.

```
df_merged = pd.merge(df1, df2[['COLUMN B', 'COLUMN F', 'COLUMN G']], on='COLUMN B', how='inner')

print(df_merged)
   COLUMN A COLUMN B COLUMN C COLUMN D COLUMN E COLUMN F COLUMN G
0         1      XYZ        A        B        D      ABA      BBA
1         2   YZX.12        E        F        G      CCA      CAC
2         3  ZYX.567        H        I        J      AAA      ABB
```

Comment: I'm using df_merged = pd.merge(df1, df2[['group_list', 'Unnamed: 0', 'index']], on='group_list', how='inner')

But I get the error: KeyError: "None of [Index(['group_list', 'Unnamed: 0', 'index'], dtype='object')] are in the [index]"

Do you know what I am doing wrong?