# Creating a '0-1' column based on a list

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, seaborn

Let's say that this is head of my df:

```
   Team     Win_pct_1 Win_pct_2  
0  Memphis     0.6        0.5
1  Miami       0.4        0.6
2  Phoenix     0.7        0.4
3  Dallas      0.6        0.3
4  Boston      0.4        0.1
```

I have created a list of teams for example:

```
list = ['Miami','Dallas']
```

1) Then I want to add a column to my df based on that list. If the `df['Team']` is in the list, new column will show 1, else 0. So in the end I will get something like:

```
   Team     Win_pct_1 Win_pct_2 New_column
0  Memphis     0.6        0.5      0
1  Miami       0.4        0.6      1
2  Phoenix     0.7        0.4      0
3  Dallas      0.6        0.3      1
4  Boston      0.4        0.1      0
```

I was considering using `for index, row in df.iterrows():` or `if df.Team.isin(list)` but I don't know how to make it work.

2) Once I add new column, I want to create a relplot:

```
sns.relplot(data=df,
           x='Win_pct_1',
           y='Win_pct_2',
           hue='New_column')
```

And I would like to know whether there is a fast way to add annotations to such plot based on my list (it can be simple annotations just above a right dot, no arrows) or it is impossible in Python (In R that is pretty easy) and I have to 
create as many `plt.annotate` as necessary.

Comment: Check with isin

Answer (score 0):

For your first question, you can use a ternary with `np.where` and `isin`:

```
df['New_column'] = np.where(df['Team'].isin(my_list), 1, 0)
```

Another alternative:

```
df['New_column'] = df['Team'].isin(my_list).astype(int)
```

Comment: Thank you so much! That is what I was looking for.

Answer (score 0):

Here's with annotations:

```
df['New_column'] = df['Team'].isin(list).astype(int)

fig, ax = plt.subplots(1, figsize=(8,8))

sns.set_style('whitegrid')
p1 = sns.scatterplot(data=df,
           x='Win_pct_1',
           y='Win_pct_2',
           hue='New_column')

p1.set_xlim(0,1)
p1.set_ylim(0,1)

for i in df.index:
    p1.text(df.at[i, 'Win_pct_1'] + .01,
            df.at[i, 'Win_pct_2'] + .01,
            df.at[i, 'Team'],
            horizontalalignment='left',
            size='medium',
            color='black')
```

Output:

[image: output]

**Update:**

For only selected teams from the list:

```
df['New_column'] = df['Team'].isin(list).astype(int)

fig, ax = plt.subplots(1, figsize=(8,8))

sns.set_style('whitegrid')
p1 = sns.scatterplot(data=df[df['New_column']==1],
           x='Win_pct_1',
           y='Win_pct_2',
           hue='New_column')

p1.set_xlim(0,1)
p1.set_ylim(0,1)

for i in df[df['New_column']==1].index:
    p1.text(df.at[i, 'Win_pct_1'] + .01,
            df.at[i, 'Win_pct_2'] + .01,
            df.at[i, 'Team'],
            horizontalalignment='left',
            size='medium',
            color='black')
```

Output:

[image: output(2)]

**Note:**

Please see [How to implement 'in' and 'not in' for Pandas dataframe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19960077/how-to-implement-in-and-not-in-for-pandas-dataframe) for more details on how to do `in/not in` in DataFrames

Comment: Thanks so much! However is it possible to modify it a bit so only Dallas and Miami will be plotted (in other words only teams from the list)? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Yes, sure, you can do `p1 = sns.scatterplot(data=df[df['New_column']==1]...` and `for i in df[df['New_column']==1].index:...` when annotating

Comment: Please see "Update" section of my answer for an example

Comment: And here's some useful samples of how to do `in/not in`: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19960077/how-to-implement-in-and-not-in-for-pandas-dataframe

Comment: Exactly what I wanted! Thank you so much.