# Pandas filter rows based on condition, but always retain the first row

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I would like to drop some rows that meets certain conditions but I do not want to drop the first row even if the first row meets that criteria.

I tried dropping rows by using the df.drop function but it will erase the first row if the first row meets that condition. I do not want that.

Data looks something like this:

```
Column1 Column2 Column3
  1        3      A
  2        1      B
  3        3      C
  4        1      D
  5        1      E
  6        3      F
```

I want to do it in a way that if a row has a value of 3 in column2 then drop it.

And I want the new data to be like this (after dropping but keeping the first one even though the first row had a value of 3 in column 2):

```
Column1 Column2 Column3
  1        3      A
  2        1      B
  4        1      D
  5        1      E
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can make "retain first row" a part of your condition for dropping/keeping rows.

The condition for keeping the rows would be `<ORIGINAL CONDITION> or <CONDITION TO KEEP FIRST ROW>`. In code, this is

```
# (condition to drop 3) | (condition to keep 0th row)
df[(df['Column2'] != 3) | (df.index == 0)]

   Column1  Column2 Column3
0        1        3       A
1        2        1       B
3        4        1       D
4        5        1       E
```

Inversely, using DeMorgan's Laws, the condition for dropping rows would be `(df['Column2'] == 3) & (df.index != 0)`. We then invert the condition to get our expected output,

```
df[~((df['Column2'] == 3) & (df.index != 0))]

   Column1  Column2 Column3
0        1        3       A
1        2        1       B
3        4        1       D
4        5        1       E
```

These work assuming your index is a `RangeIndex`. If not, use `pd.RangeIndex(len(df)) == 0` as the second condition instead.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Would it be okay to ask an additional question? Let's say if I had other values in Column2 so basically I only want to keep 1 and remove any other values (not just 3 but like 2, 4, 5, 6, 7 and so on).

Comment: @cck1110 You can use `isin`. More information [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19960077/how-to-implement-in-and-not-in-for-pandas-dataframe).

Comment: @cck1110 You can also write your condition as `df[(df['Column2'] == 1) | (df.index == 0)]` if 1 is the only thing you want to keep.

Comment: I tried the method df[(df['Column2'] == 1) | (df.index == 0)] but if the first row's value for [column2] is "2" for example, then it will remove that first row as well.

Comment: @cck1110 I tried exactly that and it works for me. Maybe your index is different. Try: `df2 = df[(df['Column2'] == 1) | (pd.RangeIndex(len(df)) == 0)]`

Comment: @cck1110 ha! I knew it. That was in my answer from way before. Be sure to read my answer more carefully next time :p

Answer (score 2):

I am using `duplicated`

```
df[(~df.Column2.duplicated())|df.Column2.ne(3)]
   Column1  Column2 Column3
0        1        3       A
1        2        1       B
3        4        1       D
4        5        1       E
```

Answer (score 2):

Already great answers posted here, but just for your convenience. We can also use [`cumcount`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.cumcount.html) for this to rank `Nth` 3 we find:

```
df = df[~((df.groupby('Column2').Column2.cumcount() != 0) & (df.Column2 == 3))]

print(df)
   Column1  Column2 Column3
0        1        3       A
1        2        1       B
3        4        1       D
4        5        1       E
```