# Selective multiplication of a pandas dataframe

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

I have a pandas Dataframe and Series of the form

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'Key':[2345,2542,5436,2468,7463],
                   'Segment':[0] * 5,
                   'Values':[2,4,6,6,4]})
print (df)
    Key  Segment  Values
0  2345        0       2
1  2542        0       4
2  5436        0       6
3  2468        0       6
4  7463        0       4

s = pd.Series([5436, 2345])
print (s)
0    5436
1    2345
dtype: int64
```

In the original df, I want to multiply the 3rd column(Values) by 7 except for the keys which are present in the series. So my final df should look like

[image]

What should be the best way to achieve this in Python 3.x?

Comment: [Please don't post images of code/data (or links to them)](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-may-i-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question)

Comment: Have a look at `https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19960077/how-to-implement-in-and-not-in-for-pandas-dataframe also please do not paste images of data/code

Answer (score 3):

Use [`DataFrame.loc`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.loc.html) with [`Series.isin`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.isin.html) for filter `Value` column with inverted condition for non membership with multiple by scalar:

```
df.loc[~df['Key'].isin(s), 'Values'] *= 7
print (df)
    Key  Segment  Values
0  2345        0       2
1  2542        0      28
2  5436        0       6
3  2468        0      42
4  7463        0      28
```

Answer (score 0):

Another method could be using numpy.where():

```
df['Values'] *= np.where(~df['Key'].isin([5436, 2345]), 7,1)
```