# Conditional Sub setting in Python

Tags: python, pandas

I am working on a project for a third party. I'm utilizing census data to support their own data to help gain better insights. I'm still in the data carpentry phase and have run into a roadblock. I know how to do the following in R, but am required to use python3 due some later machine learning packages I'd like to run. My main dataframe (`cleankc_zip`) is 9 columns by 9,062 rows, and `zipcode` is the column I want to target to subset.

I have a list of zip codes and I'd like to "subset" my data like I'd do in R.

I have a list `n` set up like this: `n = [int641, int642,...int64n]`

I've tried creating a list and using `.loc` and `.iloc` to parse through the data, like this: `zip_ksmo=cleankc_zip.loc[cleankc_zip['zipcode'] == n]` where zip_ksmo is the variable I'd like to store the new data in and cleankc_zip is the data I'm trying to subset. N is my list of zip codes, as mentioned above.

Upon running the code, I get this error: `ValueError: Lengths must match to compare`.

Basically, I would just like to subset my cleankc_zip to include only zip coded contained in my list `n`. I'm not very proficient at python and have run into a road block.

On a side note, once I get past here, I'll be good to go.

Comment: `zip_ksmo=cleankc_zip.loc[cleankc_zip['zipcode'].isin( n)]`

Comment: wooooowwwww. Thank you so much!

Comment: Happy coding :-)

Comment: More info: https://stackoverflow.com/a/55554709/4909087