# Select rows from dataframe that their specific column value equal the column of another dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, select, rows

I have `df1` which has:

```
c1 c2 c3 c4 c5
42 32 75 23 wq
63 2332 343 232 tr
87 675 305 2 iu
15 82 10 33 tr
```

And `df2` which has:

```
c1 c2 c3 c4 c5
87 42 97 53 fe
74 22 98 223 wq
87 675 784 321 iu
31 92 84 865 wq
```

I want to return the rows of `df2` in which the values of `c5` in `df2` exist in `c5` of `df1`

So, as a result; the output would be like that:

`result`

```
c1 c2 c3 c4 c5
74 22 98 223 wq
87 675 784 321 iu
31 92 84 865 wq
```

Comment: See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55554709/4909087), the solution is to use `isin`: `df2[df2['c5'].isin(df1['c5'])`

Comment: Thanks a lot, it's works with me

Comment: Please feel free to upvote the answers in the link if you found them helpful. Yw