# pandas removes rows conditionally on 2 variable values

Tags: pandas, dataframe

I have a  gender column and I only want to drop the ones that are not "MALE" or "FEMALE". How can I use a conditional with 2 variables.

I tried :

```
train2=train[train.gender = ("FEMALE" | "MALE")]
```

gives me the error :

```
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

I could maybe only do one conditional , save it in 2 variables, and then stitch them together again somehow, but that seems very inefficient.

Comment: Use `isin` with a valid iterable

Comment: Can you post a sample of your data with the expected output? Just five lines will do

Comment: `train2=train[(train.gender == "FEMALE")  | (train.gender == "MALE")]` or `train2 = train[train.isin(["FEMALE","MALE"])`

Comment: Recommend reading [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55554709/4909087).