# How to slice by checkng a list of conditions in Pandas

Tags: pandas

You can slice the dataframe by a equality check

```
df[df['column'] == 'key']
```

How do I slice the dataframe via a check into a set?

```
df[df['column'] in set(['key', 'key2', key3'])]
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Select rows from a DataFrame based on values in a column in pandas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17071871/select-rows-from-a-dataframe-based-on-values-in-a-column-in-pandas)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to implement 'in' and 'not in' for Pandas dataframe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19960077/how-to-implement-in-and-not-in-for-pandas-dataframe)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
df[df["column"].isin(["key1", "key2", "key3"])]
```

This will do it.