# Pandas filter rows based on values within a list

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Given the df

```
df=pd.DataFrame([[0.23,"A1",10],[5.36,"A2",55],[8.8,"A3",4]],
            index=list('pqr'),
            columns=list('abc'))
```

And the following list

```
lst = ['A30','A50','A2','A0']
```

I would like to print the rows from the DF which values matches any of the values within the list, for the df and list above I would expect the output to be something like

```
Out[169]: 
    a    b   c
q  5.36  A2  55
```

But the closest I've got is this

```
mask=df.isin(lst)
df[mask].dropna(axis=0,how="all")
Out[170]: 
    a   b   c
q NaN  A2 NaN
```

The 'NaN' are result of doing "df[mask]" but I don't understand why neither if I'm doing right to get the output I want to.

Is there a way to achieve the output sample I mentioned above/next ?

```
Out[169]: 
    a    b   c
q  5.36  A2  55
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just apply `any` on the result of `isin`.

```
df[df.isin(lst).any(axis=1)]

      a   b   c
q  5.36  A2  55
```

I've written more about this in [How to implement 'in' and 'not in' for Pandas dataframe](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55554709/4909087) under the "Filter on MANY Columns" section.

Comment: @Yuca This is one place where vectorization beats list comp ;)

Comment: btw, I voted for you for moderator, did you get it?

Comment: @Yuca [moderators have a diamond next to their name.](https://stackoverflow.com/users?tab=moderators) I came fourth this time. Thanks for the support! You can peruse the results [here](https://stackoverflow.com/election/11).

Comment: wow I stucked like 3 hours on this exercise before posting the question, I feel dumb now, but well at least I learnt couple of new things, thank you both of you.

Answer (score 3):

Using list comprehension:

```
[print(x) for x in [df[df[col].isin(lst)] for col in list(df)] if len(x)>0]
```

Output:

```
      a   b   c
q  5.36  A2  55
```