# Why doesn't this output list work within this code?

Tags: python, pandas

I am trying to use an output within another line of code as a list. I want to find the product code where the ordernumber equals the following values:

```
ordnumber = [10334, 10401, 10407, 10414]
```

The input:

```
(orderdetails_df.productcode).where(orderdetails_df.ordernumber == ordnumber)
```

I get back the error:

```
ValueError: Lengths must match to compare
```

Comment: Use `.isin`: `orderdetails_df.ordernumber.isin(ordnumber)`: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19960077/how-to-implement-in-and-not-in-for-pandas-dataframe

Answer (score 0):

I would do it this way:

```
orderdetails_df.loc[orderdetails_df.ordernumber.isin(ordnumber), productcode]
```