# Pandas .isin on column entries containing lists

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I am trying to filter a dataframe using the isin() function by passing in a list and comparing with a dataframe column that also contains lists. This is an extension of the question below:

[How to implement 'in' and 'not in' for Pandas dataframe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19960077/how-to-implement-in-and-not-in-for-pandas-dataframe)

For example, instead of having one country in each row, now each row contains a list of countries.

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'countries':[['US', 'UK'], ['UK'], ['Germany', 'France'], ['China']]})
```

And to filter, I set two separate lists:

```py
countries = ['UK','US']
countries_2 = ['UK']
```

The intended results should be the same because both rows 0 and 1 contain UK and/or US

```py
>>> df[df.countries.isin(countries)]
  countries
0     US, UK
1         UK
>>> df[~df.countries.isin(countries_2)]
  countries
0     US, UK
1         UK
```

However Python threw the following error

```py
TypeError: unhashable type: 'list'
```

Comment: Your dataframe code is not syntactically correct

Comment: thank you, @jezrael for fixing it

Comment: I do not think pandas gives the `TypeError: unhashable type: 'list'` error anymore for this operation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One possible solutions with sets and [`issubset`](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/stdtypes.html#frozenset.issubset) or [`isdisjoint`](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/stdtypes.html#frozenset.isdisjoint) with `map`:

```
print (df[df.countries.map(set(countries).issubset)])
  countries
0  [US, UK]

print (df[~df.countries.map(set(countries).isdisjoint)])
  countries
0  [US, UK]
1      [UK]

print (df[df.countries.map(set(countries_2).issubset)])
  countries
0  [US, UK]
1      [UK]

print (df[~df.countries.map(set(countries_2).isdisjoint)])
  countries
0  [US, UK]
1      [UK]
```