# Filter Pandas Dataframe based on List of substrings

Tags: python, pandas

I have a Pandas Dataframe containing multiple colums of strings.
I now like to check a certain column against a list of allowed substrings and then get a new subset with the result.

```
substr = ['A', 'C', 'D']
df = pd.read_excel('output.xlsx')
df = df.dropna()
# now filter all rows where the string in the 2nd column doesn't contain one of the substrings
```

The only approach I found was creating a List of the corresponding column an then do a list comprehension, but then I loose the other columns. Can I use list comprehension as part of e.g. `df.str.contains()`?

```
year  type     value   price
2000  ty-A     500     10000
2002  ty-Q     200     84600
2003  ty-R     500     56000
2003  ty-B     500     18000
2006  ty-C     500     12500
2012  ty-A     500     65000
2018  ty-F     500     86000
2019  ty-D     500     51900
```

expected output:

```
year  type     value   price
2000  ty-A     500     10000
2006  ty-C     500     12500
2012  ty-A     500     65000
2019  ty-D     500     51900
```

Comment: Please share a sample dataframe and expected output

Comment: Try `df[df.iloc[:, 2].str.contains('|'.join(substr))]`

Comment: @yatu, is there an easy way to format tables into a question?

Comment: Just paste the data directly. Make sure to TAB it before pasting

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to implement 'in' and 'not in' for Pandas dataframe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19960077/how-to-implement-in-and-not-in-for-pandas-dataframe)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use [`pandas.Series.isin`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.isin.html)

```py
>>> df.loc[df['type'].isin(substr)]
   year type  value  price
0  2000    A    500  10000
4  2006    C    500  12500
5  2012    A    500  65000
7  2019    D    500  51900
```

Comment: Sorry my fault, I really need it to be a substring, I edited my table accordingly. But in combination with Chri's approach, that worked out!
`df.loc[df['type].str.contains('|'.join(substr))]`

Answer (score 1):

you could use [pandas.DataFrame.any](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.any.html#pandas.DataFrame.any) or [pandas.DataFrame.all](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.all.html)

if you want where all instances match

```
df.loc[df['type'].apply(lambda x: all( word in x for word in substr)
```

or if you want any from the substr

```
df.loc[df['type'].apply(lambda x: any( word in x for word in substr)
```

That should if you print or return df a filtered list.