# From one line iteration to loop to include exception management

Tags: pandas, loops, exception

I have two columns and I need to check whether the value in one column,  `all_news['Query]`, is in another column,  `all['description']` column.

I found the following solution:

```
all_news['C'] = on.apply(lambda x: x.Query in x.description, axis=1)
```

but I get the following error:

> TypeError: ("argument of type 'float' is not iterable", 'occurred at
>   index 737')

Likely because there are some weird characters the iteration cannot decipher and it seems I cannot run any exception management in a one-line iteration.

How can I unfold this one line iteration into a for loop?

Result for index 737:

Query = 'medike international'

description = 'po ketvirtadienį praūžusios liūties nukentėjo ne tik kauno miestas, bet ir rajonas. pliaupiant lietui prie vilkijos vydūno alėjos esančioje apžvalgos aikštelėje ...'

Comment: Have you checked the answers on [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19960077/how-to-filter-pandas-dataframe-using-in-and-not-in-like-in-sql) question?

Comment: Have you maybe tried to set the ```description```column of your DataFrame to string type? Something like df["description"] = df["description"].astype(str)``` ? It looks like pandas is reading a float at a certain index.

Comment: @tibbles I tried, but no success.

Comment: @erfan is not a perfect match, df['Query'] is often a substring of df['description']..therefore they would not merge.

Comment: Include a small example dataset. You probably need `str.contains`, you don't need a for loop

Comment: And could you by any chance display what the columns ```Query``` and ```description``` give at index 737?

Comment: I added the results for  all_news.iloc[737:738,4:6]

Comment: The strings both look fine... but just to make sure: do you want to check if the string in ```query``` is contained in the string in ```description``` for the same row, or if the string in ```query``` is contained in the overall ```description``` column?

Comment: In the latter case, why wouldn't something simpler like ```all_news['C'] = all_news["Query"].isin(all_news["description"])``` work?

Comment: I guess it can work also in the latter case, more expensive in terms of approach, but it does the trick