# Remove a specified columns of a multiindex dataframe pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I have a problem on removing a specified column of a multiindex dataframe.

Suppose we have this `df`:

```
df.columns
MultiIndex([('Status', 'Group A', 'PASS'),
            ('Status', 'Group A', 'Not PASS'),
            ('Status', 'Group A', 'Absent'),
            ('Status', 'Group B', 'PASS'),
            ('Status', 'Group B', 'Not PASS'),
            ('Status', 'Group B', 'Absent'),
            ('Status', 'Group B', nan),
            ('Status', 'Group C', 'PASS'),
            ('Status', 'Group C', 'Not PASS'),
            ('Status', 'Group C', 'Absent')],
           names=[None, 'Group', 'Status'])
```

And we want to create a new dataframe based on `df` and only want to extract `['Not Pass', 'Absent']` only.

Is there any way to slice/remove the unnecessary columns on the dataframe ?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to filter Pandas dataframe using 'in' and 'not in' like in SQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19960077/how-to-filter-pandas-dataframe-using-in-and-not-in-like-in-sql)

Answer (score 0):

Use [slicing](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/user_guide/advanced.html#using-slicers) for exctract levels, first `:` mean all rows, first, second `:` in `idx` means all values in first, second level and list is for filtering:

```
idx = pd.IndexSlice
df = df.loc[:, idx[:, :, ['Not Pass', 'Absent']]]
```

Alternative:

```
df = df.loc[:, df.columns.get_level_values(2).isin(['Not Pass', 'Absent'])]
```

If want remove columns only inverse mask by `~`:

```
df = df.loc[:, ~df.columns.get_level_values(2).isin(['Not Pass', 'Absent'])]
```