# Python Pandas only keep row if match

Tags: python, pandas

I have a CSV loaded into Pandas that looks like this...

```
col1  |  col2  |  col3  |  col4
--------------------------------
1     |  red   |  big   |  round
1     |  blue  |  small |  square
1     |  pink  |  small |  triangle
1     |  puple |  big   |  rectangle
1     |  green |  big   |  round
```

I want to only keep rows where col4 is either round or triangle. I know I can do this...

```
df[df.col4 == 'round']
```

But how do I also include triangle in this conditinoal?

But how can I do the opposite and only keep the row if round or traignle?

Comment: `df.col4.isin(['round','triangle'])`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A really good example of this has been provided in another answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/19960116/6294483

For your specific case:

You should use the [pandas.DataFrame.isin()](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.isin.html#pandas.DataFrame.isin) method.

For example in your case:

```
print(df[df.col4.isin(['round','triangle'])])
```

Should give you the following output:

```
   col1   col2   col3      col4
0     1    red    big     round
2     1   pink  small  triangle
4     1  green    big     round
```

If you wanted opposite you could use [boolean vector operations (specifically the ~ operator)](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html#boolean-indexing):

```
print(df[~df.col4.isin(['round','triangle'])] )
```

Which should give you the following:

```
   col1   col2   col3       col4
1     1   blue  small     square
3     1  puple    big  rectangle
```

Comment: Thanks for that example and link, would this still be the appropriate method to use if I wanted to output the result as a seperate CSV instead of print?

Comment: Yes absolutely. Have a look at the pandas.DataFrame.to_csv() method https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_csv.html#pandas-dataframe-to-csv
So in your case it would be as simple as df[~df.col4.isin(['round','triangle'])].to_csv('output_file.csv')