# Appending rows in a dataframe in a for loop

Tags: pandas

I have a Dataframe1 that is with a length of 4000, and I have a list with a length of 600.

I want to compare the list with a column from the Dataframe1 and if they have the same value I want to move the row of the Dataframe1 to Dataframe2 and if not I want to move it to Dataframe3

so this was my code but it takes forever to run, can anyone recommend a faster solution.

```
for i in range(len(Dataframe1)):
    for j in range(len(list)):
         if Dataframe1['Column'][i] == list[j]:
              Datafram2 = Dataframe2.append(Dataframe1.loc[[i]])
         else:                  
              Datafram3 = Dataframe3.append(Dataframe1.loc[[i]])
```

Comment: i think @HoaNguyen's solution should suffice; also it is helpful if u share data with expected output. it helps a whole lot more than just words

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to filter Pandas dataframe using 'in' and 'not in' like in SQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19960077/how-to-filter-pandas-dataframe-using-in-and-not-in-like-in-sql)

Answer (score 0):

I think you can use `.isin()` instead of doing the loop.
To learn more, you can see: [pandas.Series.isin](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.isin.html#pandas.Series.isin), and [pandas.DataFrame.isin](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.isin.html)

Here is my suggestion:

Add rows that have `Column` in the `list` from `Dataframe1` to `DataFrame2`

```
Dataframe2 = pd.concat([Dataframe2, Dataframe1[Dataframe1["Column"].isin(list)]],ignore_index=True)
```

Add rows that have `Column` not in the `list` from `Dataframe1` to `DataFrame3`

```
Dataframe3 = pd.concat([Dataframe3, Dataframe1[~Dataframe1["Column"].isin(list)]],ignore_index=True)
```