# How to filter data by column content?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I imported CSV file with data about airports. Countries are in column "Country Name". I want to work only with data about Ukrainian, German and Polish airports. I filtered my data, but I only know how to pick one country. How I can filter my data for two or more desired countries? I'm using python 3.8.1.

My code:

```
filtered_data = df[df["Country Name"]=="Poland"]
print(filtered_data)
```

Comment: or [How to filter Pandas dataframe using 'in' and 'not in' like in SQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19960077/how-to-filter-pandas-dataframe-using-in-and-not-in-like-in-sql)

Comment: You can use something like -  "df.isin({'Country Name': ['Poland', 'German', 'Ukrainian']})"

Answer (score 1):

I guess you need this

```py
filtered_data = df[(df["Country Name"]=="Poland") | (df["Country Name"]=="Germany") | (df["Country Name"]=="Ukraine")]
print(filtered_data)
```

To specify multiple conditions, you need to combine the various conditions using `boolean` operators **(NOTE: `&` instead of `and`, `|` instead of `or`, so on)