# How to apply function which refers to several columns to pandas dataframe?

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, function

I am trying to apply function which refers to 2 columns to a pandas dataframe. One column that that the function is referring to has string variables, other integers.

I am getting a following error `ValueError: The truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all().`

Below is the example of what I have tried so far

```
def sd2_offshore(gas_rate,platform):
    if platform=='Stage2':
       if 0<gas_rate<900:
          return 5
       elif gas_rate>900:
          return 6
       else:
          return 0
     else:
        return 0

df2['Offshore SD2']=df2.apply(lambda row : sd2_offshore(df2['Gas_Rate_avg'],df2['Platform']))
```

`df2['Platform']` contains string values.

`df2['Gas_Rate_avg']` contains integer values

Thanks a lot in advance!

**Edit**

Adding example of the data below

```
Index Platform Gas_Rate_avg
0     Stage2   300
1     Stage2   0
2     Stage2   1100
3     Stage2   1200
4     Stage1   500
```

Expected output:

```
Index Platform  Gas_Rate_avg    Offshore_SD2
0     Stage2    300             5.00
1     Stage2    0               0.00
2     Stage2    1100            6.00
3     Stage2    1200            6.00
4     Stage1    500             0.00
```

Comment: You can't do this: `0<gas_rate<900`. Try: `if ((gas_rate  > 0) & (gas_rate < 900))`

Comment: seems like the gas_rate related conditions work the way I have written the code, it is when I introduce platform condition (the first if statement) it raises the Value Error

Comment: you might need `.isin()`. see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19960116/13328010)

Comment: @DavideBrex I have just tried rewriting the function this way, but still got a Value Error :/

def sd2_offshore(df):
    platforms=['Stage1']
    if df['Platform'].isin(platforms):
        if 0<df['Gas_Rate_avg']<900:
            return 5
        elif df['Gas_Rate_avg']>900:
            return 6
        else:
           return 0
    else:
        return 0
df2['Offshore SD2']=df2.apply(lambda row : sd2_offshore(df2))

Comment: Ow wow, it looks ,messy when I post in comments, couldn't find a better way, sorry... @DavideBrex

Comment: no problem! If you could edit your question and add an example of df2 (with some rows, and not as an image please) I can reproduce your situation and try to find a solution!

Comment: @DavideBrex I have edited my original post with sample data and expected output

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You were missing `axis=1` in apply. Try in this way:

```
def sd2_offshore(row): 
    if row["Platform"] == "Stage2": 
        if 0<row['Gas_Rate_avg']<900: 
            return 5 
        elif row['Gas_Rate_avg']>900:
            return 6
        else: 
            return 0 
    else:
        return 0 
    
df2['Offshore SD2'] = df2.apply(lambda row : sd2_offshore(row), axis=1)
df2
```

Output(`df2`):

```
      Platform  Gas_Rate_avg    Offshore SD2
Index           
0     Stage2    300            5
1     Stage2    0              0
2     Stage2    1100           6
3     Stage2    1200           6
4     Stage1    500            0
```