# How to filter a pandas dataframe to include specific values?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, filter

How to exclude rows if any of the columns in a dataframe contains non-binary (0 or 1) numbers. Not to exclude based on a specific column, but for all of the columns.

For example, we have a dataframe like this, and we want to delete row number 0, 2 and 4.

```
array = [[1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 2],
         [1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0],
         [2, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0],
         [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0],
         [1, 0, 0, 3, 0, 0, 0]]
df = pd.DataFrame(array, columns = ['AB','AC','CB','DE','FA','CD','AF'] )
```

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- Use [`.isin`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.isin.html) to create a [Boolean filter](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html#boolean-indexing), and then [`.dropna`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.dropna.html).

```py
df = df[df.isin([1, 0])].dropna()

# display(df)
    AB  AC  CB   DE  FA  CD   AF
1  1.0   0   0  1.0   0   0  0.0
3  0.0   0   0  0.0   0   1  0.0
```

Answer (score 0):

- Another Method is

```
df = df[~df.isin([0, 1])]
```

- where `~` means `not`
- Also we can use `.dropna()` at the end of the code, Instead of `~`

[Other Useful Resources](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19960116/8744576)