# Replacing a string value in one column based upon a list of other values in another column

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, string, data-cleaning

I am cleaning a dataset and I need to replace the string in column A with "foo" if column B contains one of the strings from a list of options.

I have a list of values contained in column B that I want to use to indicate that I need to replace column A

```
A   B
foo apple
foo banana
bar cherry
foo orange
bar melon
bar papaya
```

I have multiple values that could trigger a replacement.

```
list = ['papaya', 'avocado', 'cherry', 'mango']
```

using that list to inform the replacement I want to change the value in column A to foo if column B contains one of the values in the list. The results in this example would look like this.

```
A   B
foo apple
foo banana
foo cherry
foo orange
bar melon
```

Any advice helps, thanks.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to filter Pandas dataframe using 'in' and 'not in' like in SQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19960077/how-to-filter-pandas-dataframe-using-in-and-not-in-like-in-sql)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do:

```
lst = ['papaya', 'avocado', 'cherry', 'mango']
df.loc[df['B'].isin(lst), 'A'] = 'foo'
print(df)
```

**Output**

```
     A       B
0  foo   apple
1  foo  banana
2  foo  cherry
3  foo  orange
4  bar   melon
5  foo  papaya
```