# Pandas Equivalent of SQL's "Where In" with lists/tuples/iterables

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I'm having a hell of a time trying to find an answer to this, which I feel like should be straight forward.

What is the Pandas equivalent of `SELECT * FROM [TABLE] WHERE [COL1] IN (LIST)`?

Basically, I have a large dataset of ID numbers, and I want to select a certain subset of these customers. I want the entire dataframe's worth of values. I tried using `.isin()`, but I do not want boolean values. Is there a simple way to use another Dataframe column/Series/list/tuple (whatever) to select rows in another Dataframe?

For example, I have two tables/DataFrames:

Let's call the first table **cust_info**:

| cust_id | metadata1 |
| --- | --- |
| 1234 | y |
| 5678 | x |
| 4321 | x |
| 2468 | y |
| 9513 | x |
| 1473 | y |

The second table will be called **cust_orders**

| cust_id | order_date | order_total |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1234 | 2021-07-10 | 15.10 |
| 5678 | 2021-07-11 | 480.52 |
| 4321 | 2021-07-11 | 72.71 |
| 2468 | 2021-07-12 | 50.96 |
| 9513 | 2021-07-12 | 69.20 |
| 1473 | 2021-07-13 | 75.58 |

I'd like to use customers who's metadata1 value == 'y' in **cust_info**. I've created a list (or Series, or Tuple, or Set, whatever I need) using `DF1[DF1['metadata1'] == 'y']` and extracting the cust_id from that to create the list.

In this case, I want the entire row (including order_date and order_total) with cust_id == [1234, 2468, 1473]

So the SQL equivalent would be:

```
SELECT * FROM [cust_orders]
WHERE [cust_id] in 
(
SELECT * FROM [cust_info] where [metadata1] = 'y'
)
```

I know I can slice using AND/OR and &/|, but I have hundreds of values so manually typing each ID is out of the question. How would you guys do this? I feel like I'm missing something super obvious...

Thanks!

Comment: If you already have the container of values: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19960077/how-to-filter-pandas-dataframe-using-in-and-not-in-like-in-sql

Answer (score 3):

Make a list of the customer IDs where `cust_info['metadata1'] == 'y'`:

```py
valids = cust_info.loc[cust_info['metadata1'] == 'y', 'cust_id']
```

Then ask whether the ID is in that list of valid IDs:

```
cust_orders[cust_orders['custid'].isin(valids)]
```

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```py
x = cust_info[cust_info["metadata1"].eq("y")].merge(cust_orders, on="cust_id")
print(x)
```

Prints:

```
   cust_id metadata1  order_date  order_total
0     1234         y  2021-07-10        15.10
1     2468         y  2021-07-12        50.96
2     1473         y  2021-07-13        75.58
```

---

If you want only columns from `cust_orders`:

```
x = cust_info[cust_info["metadata1"].eq("y")].merge(cust_orders, on="cust_id")
print(x[cust_orders.columns])

   cust_id  order_date  order_total
0     1234  2021-07-10        15.10
1     2468  2021-07-12        50.96
2     1473  2021-07-13        75.58
```

Comment: Awesome. This is exactly what I was looking for. As silly as it may seem, I've never seen ```.eq()``` (still new to pandas for the most part). Definitely helped. Thanks Andrej!