# filter out values from dictionary and add to df

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, dictionary, data-analysis

I have a dictionary where I read an sql table:

```
df = {}
df['abc'] = pd.read_sql_table('abc', engine, schema_z2,
                                    columns = cols)
```

Now, I want to filter out data such that only those rows with values "R" and "P" from the `art` column are kept. This is what I tried after reading this code snippet somewhere.

```
df_merged = df['abc'][df['abc']['art'].isin(['R','P'])]
print(df_merged)
```

When I hover over `df_merged` in Visual Studio Code, it says that it is a dataframe, which is what I wanted. However, at the end when I run my code,`df_merged` is empty, even though it should have rows. I could be using a wrong syntax here: `df['abc'][df['abc']['art'].isin(['R','P'])]`but I am unable to identify how to change it.

A similar question [How to filter Pandas dataframe using 'in' and 'not in' like in SQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19960077/how-to-filter-pandas-dataframe-using-in-and-not-in-like-in-sql)

does not help because I am already using `isin()` and I am trying to filter values from a **dictionary** not a df initially.

and if I just do this:

```
df_merged =df['abc']['art_kennz'].isin(['R','P','SP','GP'])
```

`df_merged` shows a **Series[_bool]** type instead of **Dataframe**.

---

Edit:

I tried this with the following test data https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1cykNjViW_DacwWZNaIHWEh3E8OqxsVon/edit?usp=sharing&ouid=115380043465372211112&rtpof=true&sd=true:

```
import pandas as pd

df = {}
df['abc'] = pd.read_excel('./testing.xlsx')
print(df)

df_merged = df['abc'][df['abc']['art_kennz'].isin(['S','P','SP','GP'])]
df_merged.head()
```

and I get an empty dataset upon printing, which shouldn't be the case

Comment: Do you have an example (~10 rows) of the dataframe? This would make it a lot easier to find out what is going on.

Comment: Can you see thee updated qs? https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1cykNjViW_DacwWZNaIHWEh3E8OqxsVon/edit?usp=sharing&ouid=115380043465372211112&rtpof=true&sd=true @BrianBarbieri

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
df_merged = df[df['art'].isin(['R','P'])]['abc']
```

Comment: Did you try this? It gives me ```KeyError: 'art'``` Here's a sample data source https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/u/1/d/1cykNjViW_DacwWZNaIHWEh3E8OqxsVon/edit?usp=sharing&ouid=115380043465372211112&rtpof=true&sd=true

Comment: Couldn't have tried it until you gave a sample. Please note that there is no column name 'art', but 'art-kennz'

Comment: Ah yeah, but ofc I changed the names accordingly while testing. It's ```KeyError: 'art_kennz'``` Or did it work for you?

Answer (score 0):

I seem to be able to filter out what you want just fine:

```
import pandas as pd
df = {}
df["abc"] = pd.DataFrame({"art": ["A", "B", "C", "P", "R", "S"], "bert": [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]})
df_merged = df["abc"][df["abc"]["art"].isin(["R", "P"])]
df_merged
#{'abc':   art  bert
#3   P     4
#4   R     5}
```

> df_merged shows a Series[_bool] type instead of Dataframe.

Should be correct, since the `pandas.DataFrame.isin()` method returns a bool array whose rows satisfy the condition, so you can easily filter using that:

```
df["abc"]["art"].isin(["R", "P"])
#3    True
#4    True
#Name: art, dtype: bool
```

Comment: Could it be different because I am reading an sql table instead of a csv dataframe? https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/u/1/d/1cykNjViW_DacwWZNaIHWEh3E8OqxsVon/edit?usp=sharing&ouid=115380043465372211112&rtpof=true&sd=true Here's a sample data source

Comment: Can you see my edited qs? I get an empty df

Answer (score 0):

When I use the following dict:

```
dfs = {}
dfs["abc"] = pd.DataFrame({
    "mandant" : [9,9,9,9],
    "fk_eakopf_posnr" : [552025046,552025047,552035009,552035009],
    "zeile" : [5,5,5,5],
    "art_kennz" : ["G","G","G","S"]
})
```

I preform the following process:

```
dfs["abc"][dfs["abc"]['art_kennz'].isin(['S','P','SP','GP'])]
```

Then I get the following output:

```
mandant fk_eakopf_posnr zeile   art_kennz
3   9   552035009   5   S
```

Is this what you want?

Comment: What is the end result that you want, that is unclear to me. I thought you wanted a dict with values that are filtered dataframes.

Comment: Nope, I wanted the opposite. I am reading content into a dictionary and I want the end result in a df but as shown in the edited part of my question, the final df I get is empty

Comment: I have updated by comment, it looks like it all works?

Comment: Yup, this is what I would want but I don't get this when I read the file instead of manually creating a df ```df['cgo_eafapo_t'] = pd.read_excel('./testing.xlsx')```

Comment: Are you sure that the object you are putting in the dictionary is exactly the same as the created dataframe? Please inspect this thoroughly. Also I would not recommend using "df" as the variable name of a dictionary, since it is commonly used for dataframes and could confuse others.

Comment: The object I am loading into the dictionary is basically this file https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/u/1/d/1cykNjViW_DacwWZNaIHWEh3E8OqxsVon/edit?usp=sharing&ouid=115380043465372211112&rtpof=true&sd=true I don't understand why it wouldn't work if the dataframe is working

Comment: For the same excel sheet, if I check this, ```df_merged = df['cgo_eafapo_t'][df['cgo_eafapo_t']['zeile'].isin([5])]```it works. Maybe because all values in that zeile column are 5. However, the same thing doesn't work for the art_kennz column

Comment: Ah I figured it's because of extra spaces in the art column :(