# pandas create a subset according to a value in a column

Tags: python, dataframe, subset

I have this dataframe:

```
86,1/28/2004 0:00:00,16.9
86,5/25/2004 0:00:00,17.01
86,7/22/2004 0:00:00,17.06
87,11/15/2004 0:00:00,7.39
87,3/14/2005 0:00:00,7.59
86,11/15/2004 0:00:00,17.29
86,3/14/2005 0:00:00,17.38
86,4/19/2005 0:00:00,17.43
86,5/19/2005 0:00:00,17.28
87,1/22/2004 0:00:00,7.44
87,5/13/2004 0:00:00,7.36
```

I would like to work on two separate dataframe according to the value (`id`) of the first column. Ideally, I would like to have:

```
87,11/15/2004 0:00:00,7.39
87,3/14/2005 0:00:00,7.59
87,1/22/2004 0:00:00,7.44
87,5/13/2004 0:00:00,7.36
```

and

```
86,1/28/2004 0:00:00,16.9
86,5/25/2004 0:00:00,17.01
86,7/22/2004 0:00:00,17.06
86,11/15/2004 0:00:00,17.29
86,3/14/2005 0:00:00,17.38
86,4/19/2005 0:00:00,17.43
86,5/19/2005 0:00:00,17.28
```

As you can see I have one dataframe with all 87 in the first column and another with 86.

This is how I read the dataframe:

```py
dfr = pd.read_csv(fname,sep=',',index_col=False,header=None)
```

I think that `groupby` is not the right options, if I have understood correctly the command.

I was thinking about query as:

```py
aa = dfr.query(dfr.iloc[:,0]==86)
```

However, I have this error:

```
 expr must be a string to be evaluated, <class 'pandas.core.series.Series'> given
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to filter Pandas dataframe using 'in' and 'not in' like in SQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19960077/how-to-filter-pandas-dataframe-using-in-and-not-in-like-in-sql)

Comment: `aa = dfr[dfr[0].eq(86)]`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Another way to do it dynamically without having to specify the group beforehand.

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'ID': np.repeat([1, 2, 3], 4), 'col2': np.repeat([10, 11, 12], 4)})
```

Get the unique groupings:

```
groups = df['ID'].unique()
```

Create an empty dict to store new data frames

```
new_dfs = {}
```

Loop through and create new data frames from the slice:

```
for group in groups:
    name = "ID" + str(group)
    new_dfs[name] = df[df['ID'] == group]

new_dfs['ID1']
```

Which gives:

```
ID  col2
0   1   10
1   1   10
2   1   10
3   1   10
```

Answer (score 3):

You can simply slice your dataframe:

```
df_86 = df.loc[df['ColName'] == 86,:]
```