# How to remove some rows in a dataframe which are not in a list

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a pandas data frame, lets call it `df` looking like this

```
|Rank| Country         | All    | Agr    |Ind  |Dom   |
-------------------------------------------------------
|1   |Argentina        |2       |3       |1    |5     |
|4   |Chile            |3       |3       |4    |3     |
|3   |Colombia         |1       |2       |1    |4     |
|4   |Mexico           |3       |5       |4    |2     |
|3   |Panama           |2       |1       |5    |4     |
|2   |Peru             |3       |3       |4    |2     |
```

I want to remove from the rows that **are not** in the next list:

```
paises = ["Colombia", "Peru", "Chile"]
```

For that I tried this code:

```
df = df.drop(df["Country"]= paises)
```

But it did not work, because they do not have the same length.

I´m so rookie in python. Can you help me?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to filter Pandas dataframe using 'in' and 'not in' like in SQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19960077/how-to-filter-pandas-dataframe-using-in-and-not-in-like-in-sql)

Comment: https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.drop.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use pandas.dataFrame.[isin](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.isin.html)()

Create an appropriate dataFrame [mask](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.mask.html) using the list of countries you don't want in your dataFrame.

```
paises = ["Colombia", "Peru", "Chile"]
df[df['country'].isin(paises)==False]
```

Use the dataFrame mask to assign the masked dataFrame, which excludes the paises.

```
paises = ["Colombia", "Peru", "Chile"]
df = df[df['country'].isin(paises)==False]

>>> df
   Rank    Country  All  Agr  Ind  Dom
0     1  Argentina    2    3    1    5
3     4     Mexico    3    5    4    2
4     3     Panama    2    1    5    4
```

You can also use the [not isin()](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.isin.html) operator "~" to check if values are not in the DataFrame. To use the ~ operator: `df = df[~df['country'].isin(paises)]`

You don't even need the hand of Maradona for this one.

Answer (score 2):

Use `isin`:

```
df = df[~df['Country'].isin(paises)]
```

Output:

```
>>> df
   Rank    Country  All  Agr  Ind  Dom
0     1  Argentina    2    3    1    5
3     4     Mexico    3    5    4    2
4     3     Panama    2    1    5    4
```

Answer (score 1):

I would use the following

```
df = df[~df["Country"].isin(paises)]
```

Using negation sign `~`.