# Find the column value based on condition

Tags: python, pandas, data-analysis

I need to find unique name, whose age=2 and and cond=9 using python pandas?

| name | age | cond | cc |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| a | 2 | 9 | 3 |
| b | 2 | 8 | 2 |
| c | 3 | 9 | 1 |
| a | 2 | 9 | 6 |

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to filter Pandas dataframe using 'in' and 'not in' like in SQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19960077/how-to-filter-pandas-dataframe-using-in-and-not-in-like-in-sql)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Pandas [query](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.query.html) function allows for SQL-like queries to filter a data frame. Then use unique() on the results to return the unique name.

```
rows = df.query('age == 2 and cond == 9')
print(rows["name"].unique())
```

For more query examples, see [here](https://sparkbyexamples.com/pandas/pandas-dataframe-query-examples/).

Answer (score 1):

This will find all distinct rows where age = 2 and cond = 9

```
df.loc[(df['age'] == 2) & (df['cond'] == 9)][['name', 'cc']].drop_duplicates()
```

Comment: i need unique value of column name..can you help me?

Comment: You just need the values of column 'name' where they are distinct?

Comment: yes...the unique column name value..

Comment: Thankyou so much..if i need the column cc value with name..what i need to do?

Comment: Edited again to add cc to the list of columns to include

Comment: No problem, if this answers your question please make sure to make it as "answered" so that other seeking the same question can find an answer

Answer (score 0):

One potential solution is to put the columns in a `zip()` and then iterate through your dataframe like so:

```
for name, age, cond in zip(df['name'], df['Age'], df['cond']):
    if(age == 2 and cond ==9):
      print(name)
```

Comment: Hi..thankyou.. I need unique value..can you help me?