# Accessing all the rows with a same particular element from the pandas dataframe

Tags: pandas, dataframe

I have this particular dataset in a CSV file, I want to find out the names of all crops that grow in the summer season. How can I do that?

[image]

Comment: Hello @Anvesh Mandlik, welcome to stackoverflow.  What did you already try? Have you read this [how to ask page](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to filter Pandas dataframe using 'in' and 'not in' like in SQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19960077/how-to-filter-pandas-dataframe-using-in-and-not-in-like-in-sql)

Answer (score 0):

You can use [**`pandas.DataFrame.loc`**](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.loc.html) to return the rows of every crop that grows in the summer.

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_csv('anvesh.csv')

mask = df['Season']=='Summer'
out= df.loc[mask]
```

##### `>>> display(out)`

[image]

And if you need to get a list of all these crops, you can use this :

```
list(out['Crop'])
['Moong(Green Gram)'] #Output
```