# How can I exclude words from frequency word analysis in a list of articles in python?

Tags: python, word-frequency

I have a dataframe `df` with a column "Content" that contains a list of articles extracted from the internet. I have already the code for constructing a dataframe with the expected output (two columns, one for the word and the other for its frequency). However, I would like to exclude some words (conectors, for instance) in the analysis. Below you will find my code, what should I add to it?

It is possible to use the code `get_stop_words('fr')` for a more efficiente use? (Since my articles are in French).

##### Source Code

```py
    import csv
    from collections import Counter
    from collections import defaultdict

    import pandas as pd


    df = pd.read_excel('C:/.../df_clean.xlsx', 
                                sheet_name='Articles Scraping')
    df = df[df['Content'].notnull()]
    d1 = dict()

    for line in df[df.columns[6]]:
        words = line.split()
        # print(words)
        for word in words:
            if word in d1:
                d1[word] += 1
            else:
                d1[word] = 1

    sort_words = sorted(d1.items(), key=lambda x: x[1], reverse=True)
```

Comment: [How to filter Pandas dataframe using 'in' and 'not in' like in SQL](https://stackoverflow.com/q/19960077/16509954)

Comment: Create a list of words and then use the string contains to return a dataframe where you apply the NOT condition: `~df.C.str.contains()`.

Comment: Create a list of "connectors" that you want to avoid, then apply an "include" operator, you could follow the python operator `in` or you could use same operator from the `pandas` library, it is up to you. The "include" operator should be write between the `for` loop and the first `if` conditional.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. However, it's not that clear for me where and how exactly to add this "include" operator. Would it be possible for you to include it in my code? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

There are a few ways you can achieve this. You can either use the `isin()` method with a list comprehension,

```
data = {'test': ['x', 'NaN', 'y', 'z', 'gamma',]}

df = pd.DataFrame(data)

words = ['x', 'y', 'NaN']

df = df[~df.test.isin([word for word in words])]
```

Or you can go with not string contains and a join:

```
df = df[~df.test.str.contains('|'.join(words))]
```

If you want to utilize the stop words package for French, you can also do that, but you must preprocess all of your texts before you start doing any frequency analysis.

```
french_stopwords = set(stopwords.stopwords("fr")) 
        
STOPWORDS = list(french_stopwords)
STOPWORDS.extend(['add', 'new', 'words', 'here'])
```

I think the `extend()` will help you tremendously.

Comment: Thanks! But when i run this command I have "'DataFrame' object has no attribute 'test'" as a result. I think it is because I am analyzing a column in a dataframe a not a dictionary ('data' in your example)

Comment: The `test` in `df[~df.test.isin([word for word in words])]
` is the name of the column, so just change it with your column name. I am calling that on my dataframe (`df`), not on `data`.