# How do you filter rows in a dataframe containing values in another dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas

I have a column with in a dataframe that I want to filter the dataframe with based on which rows contain values that are in another dataframe.

In other words, I have a blacklist of keywords that I want to make sure are not in a dataframe.

Answer (score 0):

To select rows whose column value is in an iterable, `some_values`, use `isin`:

```
df.loc[df['column_name'].isin(some_values)]
```

You can convert your whitelist of keywords to a set, and use the solution above. A similar question that I refer to is [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17071871/how-do-i-select-rows-from-a-dataframe-based-on-column-values).

Comment: Thank you for this, but I need a way to filter based on whether or not the values contain eg df2 = df1.loc[ ~df1['userName'].str.contains(df[blacklist])

Comment: I suppose what you need is `df2 = df1[~df1['userName'].isin(df[blacklist])`, ref https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19960077/how-to-filter-pandas-dataframe-using-in-and-not-in-like-in-sql .