# Multi-processing & multi-core CPU allocation to optimize large dataframe filtering

Tags: pandas, multithreading, dataframe, filtering, cpu-usage

Hope you are well.

Quick question her. I am trying to optimize a script that is filtering through a large dataset. I understand that one way to do so is to use an "isin" method like this: df[df.mycolumn.isin(myfilter_value)]

Still, I am not getting the response time I was hoping.

Is it possible / have you tried to optimize filtering (even when using the "isin" method) by either doing some multi-threading or by forcing multi-core CPU allocation to speed up the task?

I am not even sure a filtering task could work with that sort of approach, but I'd rather ask.

Thanks for the help

Comment: Please provide more context. For example, what are the type of the items in the dataframe? what is its shape? What is the size of `myfilter_value`? A minimal working example would help a lot. Parallelism does not works well on all kind of datatypes in Python. It is also not very useful for short operations repeated a lot of time.

Comment: Sure here a link to another thread related to the same matter with a practical example.   https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74565768/optimize-dataframe-filtering-on-large-datasets-pandas?noredirect=1#comment131623128_74565768

Comment: yes and no, you are most likely bound by your speed of reading files from disk anyway, so even if you omitted the time of the filtering completely you will still get nowhere near your target speed, you need to parallelize the read and filtering, and hope your RAM and DISK are fast enough to give you a speedup and that's usually only 30% speedup, which may not always happen, so your code might run slower in the end, and python isn't that good at parallelizing disk reads from the same file .. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8424771/parallel-processing-of-a-large-csv-file-in-python

Comment: It looks like you want to filter strings, but you cannot use multithreading efficiently for that in Python because of the Global Interpreter Lock (GIL) of CPython. You need to use Multiprocessing to get a speed up but this require sending string to the other processes which is generally slow, possibly slower than the actual computation (one has to test). Python is not great for parallelism. If you could use fixed-sized Numpy string arrays (especially ASCII strings), then things could be better (even in sequential actually). Also note that strings defeat most JIT-based optimizations too.

Comment: @AhmedAEK Where did you got the "30% speedup"? Such a thing should be highly dependent of the hardware (Nvme SSD vs SATA SSD vs HDD, number of core, CPU architecture, etc.), the OS (due to the SER/DES, the IO subsystem/scheduler, etc.) and the version of the target packages (due to the optimizations).

Comment: @JérômeRichard that's around the mark of parallelizing things that are already bottlenecked by RAM and DISK speed, and reading the same file or working on the same data is usually one of these operations, but as you said it highly depends on hardware. this number is only from my trials and other online articles, i think specialized hardware or patterns can improve it, but throwing parallel at the problem on average hardware won't give much more than that.

Comment: Thank you for the answers, really interesting. @JérômeRichard when you're referring to fixed sized numpy string arrays, to make sure that I get it right: Does it mean that I should convert all my strings in my database into a suit of integers, then call those integers as numpy array, then filter & perform all my calculation on my dataframe using those arrays. And only when I get the final result, I should use a sort of look-up table to transform back those integers into readable strings?

If correct, would that help to convert only some strings but not all of them? How about keep floats?

Comment: No I mean a Numpy array of native string and not Python object (that Numpy also supports but not efficiently). For example, `np.array(['test', '123'])` is of type `<U4`. Numpy store the string in memory as a buffer of unicode character of a fixed size. The size is the one specified by the user or the biggest one of the array. ASCII string are stored as a buffer of bytes which is even more efficient (faster & smaller). The downside is that if one string is huge like 1 KiB, then Numpy will allocate 1KiB per item and the overall array can be pretty huge.