# How to add rows to new Pandas dataframe if a value is not in a different dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Let us say we have two base dataframes:

```
>>> df1
        A
0  value1  
1  value2  
2  value3 
3  value4
4  value5 


>>> df2
        A
0  value2  
1  value3 
2  value4
```

I want to create a `df3` that only has the rows where there is **not** a match for `df1.A` in `df2.A`, i.e.:

```
>>> df3
        A
0  value1  
1  value5
```

Assume that there are other columns beyond `A`, and that all the values in `A` are strings. I understand that `df.isin` may be useful here, but I don't want to output the `True` or `False` values that function produces by default.

Edit: solved here: [How to filter Pandas dataframe using 'in' and 'not in' like in SQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19960077/how-to-filter-pandas-dataframe-using-in-and-not-in-like-in-sql). A merge as suggested below would probably also work!

Comment: `df1[~df1['A'].isin(df2['A'])]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sample Code:

```
import pandas as pd

data1 = {'A': ['value1', 'value2', 'value3', 'value4', 'value5']}
data2 = {'A': ['value2', 'value3', 'value4']}
df1 = pd.DataFrame(data1)
df2 = pd.DataFrame(data2)

merged = pd.merge(df1, df2, on='A', how='left', indicator=True)
df3 = merged[merged['_merge'] == 'left_only']
df3 = df3.drop(columns=['_merge'])

print(df3)
```

Output:

```
        A
0  value1
4  value5
```