# Removing Rows that contain values in a list

Tags: python, filter, pandas, python-2.x, delete-row

I am trying to filter out a large dataframe and don't want rows that contain certain values in the column 'Product Description'.

I have looked at 
[how can i remove multiple rows with different labels in one command in pandas?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21600219/how-can-i-remove-multiple-rows-with-different-labels-in-one-command-in-pandas/21600535#21600535)

and

[Remove rows not .isin('X')](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14057007/remove-rows-not-isinx)

and applied the code. However,

```
  df[-df['label'].isin(List)]
```

is not working for me and I am not sure what to do.

Here is my exact code:

```
List2 = ['set up','setup','and install',....etc etc]
```

(I also tried List2 = ( ..etc ) with parentheses instead of brackets and it didn't work)

```
Computers_No_UNSPSC =Compters_No_UNSPSC[- Computers_No_UNSPSC['Product Description'].isin(List2)]
```

(I also tried using ~ instead of - which didn't work)

Is there something that I am doing wrong/missing. When I look at my Computers_No_UNSPSC dataframe, I see that there are rows still containing words in the list I created. It doesn't seem to filter out what I don't want.

Thanks for the help!

**I believe the List2 is working. I have rows of data that where people are describe their computer purchases. I want all computers bought not 'computer repair' or 'computer software'.
So I created a list that seems to capture peripherals/things I don't want...well when I say

```
print List2
```

I get

```
['set up', 'setup', 'and install', ' server', 'labor', 'services', 'processing', 'license', 'renewal', 'repair', 'case', 'speakers', 'cord', 'support', 'cart', 'docking station', 'components', 'accessories', 'software', ' membership', ' headsets ', ' keyboard', ' mouse', ' peripheral', ' part', ' charger', ' battery', ' drive', ' print', ' cable', ' supp', ' usb', ' shelf', 'disk', 'memory', 'studio', 'training', 'adapter', 'wiring', 'mirror']
```

Does this mean that it recognizes each string as a word? so when I apply the filter it will filter against each of the words in my List2?

```
A =A[-A['Product Description'].isin(List2)]
```

This seems to be the part that isn't working but again, I am not sure where I went wrong.

Comment: Can you post sample data where this doesn't work and the list where it fails to match

Comment: What part exactly is not working? You're mentioning two parts: the - and the `.isin(List2)` So are both parts not working or just the one?

Answer (score 1):

I dont think you understand how that works its checking if label == anything in that list ... not if label contains anything in that list ...

It sounds like a label might look like

```
label = "set up computer"
```

isin will look for exact matches ... not partial matches

```
label in ["set","up","computer"] #is false for example
"set" in ["set","up","computer"] #is true for example
```

**note**: this obviously is not pandas `isin` but that works the same ...

to do what you want you need to check the list of words against label

```
any(word in label for word in blacklisted_words)
```

which is going to be much slower

Comment: Thanks for that explanation. I didn't understand exactly what was going on. I did try to do ... 
     C2 = C2[ (-C2['Product Description'].str.contains('set up')) | (-C2['Product Description'].str.contains('setup'))  ...etc etc but this didn't work and I believe its for the same reason

Comment: yeah :) I think your starting to understand now though :) go ahead and accept if this answers your question(even though it doesnt solve your problem).

Comment: Is there no easier vectorized way to do this with pandas? Do I have to use a for loop to filter out everything that has these words in it?

Comment: Try this - df[df.label.apply(lambda s: numpy.any([t in s for t in List2]))]