# How to use pandas to print the difference of two columns?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I have two data sets

1 set it has a column with a list of email address:

DF1

```
Email
xxxx@abc.gov
xxxx@abc.gov
xxxx@abc.gov
xxxx@abc.gov
xxxx@abc.gov
```

2nd csv
Dataframe2

```
Email
xxxx@abc.gov
xxxx@abc.gov
xxxx@abc.gov
xxxx@abc.gov
dddd@abc.com
dddd@abc.com
3333@abc.com
```

---

```
import pandas as pd

SansList = r'C:\\Sans compare\\SansList.csv'
AllUsers = r'C:\\Sans compare\\AllUser.csv'

## print Name column only and turn into data sets from CSV ##
df1 = pd.read_csv(SansList, usecols=[0])

df2 = pd.read_csv(AllUsers, usecols=[2])

**print(df1['Email'].isin(df2)==False)**
```

I want the results to be,

```
Dataframe3
dddd@abc.com
dddd@abc.com
3333@abc.com
```

Not quite sure how to fix my dataset... :(

Comment: I do not think you want to use pandas. Use sets. set(df1['Email'].values) and then  set.intersection()

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14057007/remove-rows-not-isinx

Comment: do you have another example?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

***Option 1***
*`isin`*

```
df2[~df2.Email.isin(df1.Email)]

          Email
4  dddd@abc.com
5  dddd@abc.com
6  3333@abc.com
```

***Option 2***
*`query`*

```
df2.query('Email not in @df1.Email')

          Email
4  dddd@abc.com
5  dddd@abc.com
6  3333@abc.com
```

***Option 3***
*`merge`*

`pd.DataFrame.merge` with `indicator=True`, enables you to see which dataframe the row came from.  We can then filter on it.

```
df2.merge(
    df1, 'outer', indicator=True
).query('_merge == "left_only"').drop('_merge', 1)

           Email
20  dddd@abc.com
21  dddd@abc.com
22  3333@abc.com
```

Comment: it keeps printing all of my full list of emails from df2

Comment: You need to reassign the results back to `df2`.  I did not overwrite your variable.  Just do `df2 = df2[~df2.Email.isin(df1.Email)]`

Comment: i did that, its still printing everything from my master list, its not comparing :(

Comment: Then there is something wrong with your csv files such that the things you expect to be equal are in fact not equal.

Comment: apparently pandas is case sensitive :(

Answer (score 1):

Numpy solution:

```
In [311]: df2[~np.in1d(df2.Email, df1.Email)]
Out[311]:
          Email
4  dddd@abc.com
5  dddd@abc.com
6  3333@abc.com
```

Comment: doesn't work, its printing everthing from my dataframe2, not the differences

Comment: @davidjbeiler, what do you mean? you read it in your code: `df2 = pd.read_csv(AllUsers, usecols=[2])`...

Comment: its printing everthing from my dataframe2, not the differences