# Tilde sign in pandas DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I'm new to python/pandas and came across a code snippet.

```
df = df[~df['InvoiceNo'].str.contains('C')]
```

Would be much obliged if I could know what is the tilde sign's usage in this context?

Comment: Tilde means negation, i,e in this case, `InvoiceNo` that DONT contains `C`

Comment: Dupe of https://stackoverflow.com/q/8305199

Comment: Thanks for the reference.

Comment: @Zero, arguably not a duplicate question, the question refers specifically to the context of a tilde operating on a pandas DataFrame which has behaves differently to the tilde in standard Python (e.g. Booleans), whereas the linked question asks about the tilde operator in a broad sense.

Answer (score 68, accepted):

It means bitwise not, inversing boolean mask - `False`s to `True`s and  `True`s to `False`s.

Sample:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'InvoiceNo': ['aaC','ff','lC'],
                   'a':[1,2,5]})
print (df)
  InvoiceNo  a
0       aaC  1
1        ff  2
2        lC  5

#check if column contains C
print (df['InvoiceNo'].str.contains('C'))
0     True
1    False
2     True
Name: InvoiceNo, dtype: bool

#inversing mask
print (~df['InvoiceNo'].str.contains('C'))
0    False
1     True
2    False
Name: InvoiceNo, dtype: bool
```

Filter by [`boolean indexing`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html#boolean-indexing):

```
df = df[~df['InvoiceNo'].str.contains('C')]
print (df)
  InvoiceNo  a
1        ff  2
```

So output is all rows of DataFrame, which not contains `C` in column `InvoiceNo`.

Answer (score 4):

It's used to invert boolean Series, see [pandas-doc](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html#boolean-indexing).

Answer (score 1):

```
df = df[~df['InvoiceNo'].str.contains('C')]
```

The above code block denotes that remove all data tuples from pandas dataframe, which has "C" letters in the strings values in [InvoiceNo] column.

tilde(~) sign works as a NOT(!) operator in this scenario.

**Generally above statement uses to remove data tuples that have null values from data columns**.

Answer (score -1):

tilde ~ is a bitwise operator. If the operand is 1, it returns 0, and if 0, it returns 1. So you will get the InvoiceNo values in the df that does not contain the string 'C'