# What does this line do? df = df[~df[runner].str.contains("[a-z]").fillna(False)]

Tags: python, pandas

may I check what does this line do?

```
df = df[~df[runner].str.contains("[a-z]").fillna(False)]
```

Is this code remove all rows that contain string that start with alphabet? 
2nd question is what is the purpose of ~? What does it do?

Thanks

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Tilde sign in python dataframe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46054318/tilde-sign-in-python-dataframe)

Comment: Is it possible to add in a conditional to check if there are more than 3 chars as well in 1 line?

Comment: The RegEx would be "[a-z]{3,}" which matches more than 3 characters from a to z.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**This code is masking a DataFrame.**

The RegEx `"[a-z]"` means contains any character 'a to z' (not 'starting with', as this would be `"^[a-z]"`).

The `.fillna(False)` means every NaN is treated as False for this Mask.

The `~` is inverting the Mask, so that the unselected rows are returned.

Be aware that the rows containing NaN are included. If this is not intended you must use `.fillna(True)`.

Comment: Worth noting possibly more idiomatic is to use the `na` parameter: `~df[runner].str.contains("[a-z]", na=False)` rather than using `fillna` as a subsequent step.