# How to remove duplicates when upon editing an entity the originals are not replaced?

Tags: python, pandas

Consider that we have a dataset that represents some purchases. Products that have been bought together have the same basket ID.

When a purchased product is edited (e.g. the wrong price was inserted at first) it does not replace the original record. Instead, a new record is made for **EVERY** product of that basket ID and a new Basket ID is assigned to the purchase.

For example consider a purchase of a bottle of milk and a chocolate:

```
    Product   Price BasketID   PreviousBasketID
0   Milk      2     1234       Null
1   Chocolate 3     1234       Null
```

Let's say that we'd like to edit the price of chocolate. Then the dataset would be:

```
    Product   Price BasketID   PreviousBasketID
0   Milk      2     1234       Null
1   Chocolate 3     1234       Null
2   Milk      2     5678       1234
3   Chocolate 4     5678       1234
```

Is there a way to keep only the latest version of the basket (i.e. BasketID = 5678) and get rid of any previous versions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you remove any rows that have a `BasketID` that appears in `PreviousBasketID`?

Something like:

```py
df = df[~df["BasketID"].isin(df["PreviousBasketID"])]
```

Here the `~` means bitwise not. [See here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46054318/tilde-sign-in-python-dataframe) for more info.