# Pandas DataFrame : filter column / index by type

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, data-cleaning

Here is the deal,

I'm retrieving data from a non-consistent MongoDB collection, so I want to **remove rows** where the index is **not a datetime type**.

E.g. removing the first 5 rows of this DataFrame:

```
                                               _id  id  ... open connected
updated                                                 ...               
Timestamp(0, 1610620202)  60001de14ed34a02743c4547  27  ...    1         1
1610620382                60001de14ed34a02743c4548   5  ...    1         1
1610620202                60001de14ed34a02743c4549  24  ...    1         1
1610620382                60001de14ed34a02743c454a  17  ...    1         1
1610620201                60001de14ed34a02743c454b   1  ...    1         1
...                                            ...  ..  ...  ...       ...
2021-01-14 20:12:01       6000a60cc299a51c09e20626  19  ...    1         1
2021-01-14 20:12:01       6000a60cc299a51c09e20627  21  ...    1         1
2021-01-14 20:12:01       6000a60cc299a51c09e20628  11  ...    1         1
2021-01-14 20:12:01       6000a60cc299a51c09e20629  16  ...    1         1
2021-01-14 20:12:01       6000a60cc299a51c09e2062a  14  ...    1         1
```

Also, how can I find the precise **type** used in a given cell ?
Thanks.

Comment: You can use `type(df.loc[selected_row, column)` in combination with `isinstance()` method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Convert the column to datetime and use `errors='coerce'` to mark non datetime types to `NaT` and then you can filter out the rows which are not null

```
df[~pd.to_datetime(df.index, errors='coerce').isnull()]

                                       _id      id
updated     
2021-01-14 20:12:01 6000a60cc299a51c09e20626    19
2021-01-14 20:12:01 6000a60cc299a51c09e20627    21
2021-01-14 20:12:01 6000a60cc299a51c09e20628    11
2021-01-14 20:12:01 6000a60cc299a51c09e20629    16
2021-01-14 20:12:01 6000a60cc299a51c09e2062a    14
```

To know the data type of the whole column you can do

```
df['_id'].apply(type)
```

in case of index, you can do

```
pd.Series(df.index.values).apply(type)
```

Comment: And what is the use for `~` ?

Comment: ~ is for negation https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46054318/tilde-sign-in-python-dataframe. `pd.to_datetime(df.index, errors='coerce').isnull()` finds where there are nulls. But as we want where it is not null ~ is used

Answer (score 0):

Let's create a small example with an index range and a date range:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'a':[1,2,3]})
df2 = pd.DataFrame({'a':[4,5,6]}, index=pd.date_range('2020-01-01', '2020-01-03', freq='D'))
df_select = df.append(df2)

>>> df_select 
                     a
0                    1
1                    2
2                    3
2020-01-01 00:00:00  4
2020-01-02 00:00:00  5
2020-01-03 00:00:00  6
```

Now you can select unsing type information like this:

```
df_select[[isinstance(item, pd.Timestamp) for item in df_select.index.values]]
>>>
                     a
2020-01-01 00:00:00  4
2020-01-02 00:00:00  5
2020-01-03 00:00:00  6
```

Hope this is a solution for your problem.