# Filter Data with Pandas in Pycharm

Tags: python, pandas

This is my code so far in Pycharm for my Streamlit Data app:

```
import pandas as pd
import plotly.express as px
import streamlit as st

st.set_page_config(page_title='Matching Application Number', 
                   layout='wide')
df = pd.read_csv('Analysis_1.csv')

st.sidebar.header("Filter Data:")
MeetingFileType = st.sidebar.multiselect(
    "Select File Type:",
    options=df['MEETING_FILE_TYPE'].unique(),
    default=df['MEETING_FILE_TYPE'].unique()
)

df_selection = df.query(
    'MEETING_FILE_TYPE == @MeetingFileType'
)

st.dataframe(df_selection)
```

The result of my code on streamlit is this below:

```
Application_ID    MEETING_FILE_TYPE
BBC#:1010         1     
NBA#:1111         2
BRC#:1212         1
SAC#:1412         4
QRD#:1912         2
BBA#:1092         4
```

But, I would like to filter the data and only return Application_ID results for just MEETING_FILE_TYPE 1&2.

I am looking for this result below:

```
Filter Data:               Application_ID     MEETING_FILE_TYPE
select type:               BBC#:1010          1 
1 2                        NBA#:1111          2
                           BRC#:1212          1
                           QRD#:1912          2
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The .isin() function is useful for creating a vector of Bools on which to filter the rows of your DataFrame. For filtering categorical columns, as in your example, it's the simplest way to go. Documentation [here](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.isin.html).

```
select_type = [1,2]
df = df[df['MEETING_FILE_TYPE'].isin(select_type)]
```

It's not necessary in this example, but pairing the ~, which gives the reverse Bool value, along with .isin() often comes in handy. Someone covered this [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46054318/tilde-sign-in-pandas-dataframe).

Comment: Remember that Stack Overflow isn't just intended to solve the immediate problem, but also to help future readers find solutions to similar problems, which requires understanding the underlying code. This is especially important for members of our community who are beginners, and not familiar with the syntax. Given that, **can you [edit] your answer to include an explanation of what you're doing** and why you believe it is the best approach?